# VALARM Description Is Not Showing

Tags: icalendar, rfc5545

I am trying to create a **VALARM** for a **VEVENT** with customized **VALARM** message. So based on **RFC5545**, I just have to set action to **DISPLAY** and set my customized message in the **DESCRIPTION** field of the **VALARM** component.

> "When the action is "DISPLAY", the alarm MUST also include a
>         "DESCRIPTION" property, which contains the text to be displayed
>         when the alarm is triggered."

However, even if I set the **DESCRIPTION** property, the message is still not being displayed in the alarm popup.

```
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
TRIGGER;VALUE=DURATION:-PT15M
DESCRIPTION:Test Message
END:VALARM
```

I have tried it on my iphone calendar application and Mozilla Thunderbird Lightning Addon.

Any feedback is greatly appreaciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

The formatting of your VALARM is correct, so the only logical answer is that whatever iCalendar application you are using, does not support `DESCRIPTION` (which is something I see on occasion)

Comment: do you know any calendar application that supports that?

Comment: I don't off the top of my head. I do know that iCal from apple doesn't, but that doesn't help much :) Try emClient if you're on windows, or Thunderbird + Lightning, Outlook of course, Evolution.. there's a whole bunch

Answer (score 0):

You should do it the other way round: Create a calendar event with your calendar application, export it to file and see how it looks like.

That way I solved a similar problem: I spent some time trying to import calendar events to my brand new Android 5 phone. After import all alarms were lost. It turned out that the calendar app does not fully understand ICS files (iCal Version 2.0) but the old VCS format (iCal Version 1.0). Strange but true.